# Why is the segfault signal on *nix abbreviated as 'SIGSEGV' and not 'SIGSEGF'?

Tags: unix, history, segmentation-fault

Is there any historical reason? Is there actually any reason at all or was it pure coincidence? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) failed on me this time, so I hope you can provide me with some information / an answer. :)

Comment: By the way, [Wikipedia never fails.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV#Etymology) :D

Comment: @voithos: *Ack!* Sorry, totally overlooked that...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's actually a segment *violation*.

Comment: Segmentation -- violation -- core dumped blues!

Comment: D'oh! That *does* make sense, wondering why I didn't think of it... Then how does it come it's segmentation fault / segfault now?

Comment: a segmentation violation (touching where you are not supposed to) results in a segmentation fault (the error you get).

Comment: So with the backup from Wikipedia and the comments, seems like this is the truth. Thanks for such a fast answer. :) (9minutes till accept.)